# Unable to see documents uploaded to library folders in SP2010

Tags: 2010, file-upload, library

I'm a SharePoint administrator and have recently given a colleague contribute access to a site library to upload a suite of handover folders / documents. He's successfully done this and can see the results of his uploading clearly when he accesses the library. However, me and fellow admins are unable to see any uploaded documents - only empty folders.
Why is this and what do I need to do in order to make the uploaded information publicly available?

Comment: Are you a site collection admin?

Comment: is this working for you?

Comment: Bang on, Hardik - documents weren't checked in. I now have visibility. The simplest answers are always the best (in my book)! Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Please upvote the answer as well so it will help me as well... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below things first

1. Check that your colleague has checked-in the documents. After that you will get all the documents accessible.
2. Check the permission of yourself in document library (although you said you are an administrator).